# What is the options for reporting down votes which appear to be tit for tat or malicious?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I downvoted an answer which was not correct (I checked it and found a correct answer) and came to find out that the question itself had been downvoted.

What is the options for reporting down votes which appear to be tit for tat or malicious?

Answer (score 6):

Downvoting is anonymous, and there is no way to be sure who voted.  Even moderators can't see this information.

As long as it isn't [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), there is nothing you or a moderator can do about it.

See also, [Is there a way to report drive-by downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219583/is-there-a-way-to-report-drive-by-downvotes)

Comment: a while before one of the mod indicate that he can watch in radar, is that true ?

Comment: Maybe the question itself was not clear enough in the beginning, it happens sometimes.

Comment: @Bala Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @MPD check the mod comment here http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-almost-every-question-gets-an-upvote-now

Comment: @Bala The system identifies patterns of voting likely to be fraudulent. Some of these are handled automatically, others result in a manual review.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you cannot report down-votes as not being done in good faith; it is not required, since the system already handles suspicious voting patterns, and handle them automatically.

The system doesn't provide details about each single vote a post receives to moderators; it would be difficult to analyze a single vote, and it would not probably make sense, since we are worried about serial votes that cause a user to gain too much reputation (or lose it).